# find the list of all airports in a country in prolog

Tags: prolog

This is my flightdb.pl

```
#flight(citya ,cityb)
flight(dublin, london).
flight(cork, moscow).
flight(chicago, dublin).
flight(berlin, moscow).
flight(cork, newyork).
flight(paris, hongkong).

#country(city,country)
country(dublin,ireland).
country(cork,ireland).
country(london,uk).
country(rome,italy).
country(moscow,russia).
country(hongkong,china).
country(amsterdam,holland).
country(berlin,germany).
country(paris,france).
country(newyork,usa).
country(chicago,usa). 
country(sao_paulo,brazil).
country(rio,brazil).
```

I am trying to get all the airports in the particular country

this is the predicate that I wrote

```
list_airport(X,L) :-country(L,X).
```

I have just started with prolog ,is the logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the database with:

```
?- country(X, ireland).
X = dublin ;
X = cork.
```

You can generate a list of all the matches with [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3):

```
?- findall(C, country(C, ireland), Cs).
Cs = [dublin, cork].
```

So if you want to obtain a list of cities for a given country, you can use:

```
list_airport(C, L) :-
    findall(Ci, country(Ci, C), L).
```

and query with:

```
?- list_airport(usa, L).
L = [newyork, chicago].
```

Comment: @gANDALF: well your `list_airport/2` will not return a list, but unify `L` with airpoirts. That is not per se wrong. But you do not really need to define a `list_airport/2` predicate if that is the case, since then `list_airport/2` is just a "swapped" version of `country/2`.

Comment: Hi can you answer this question please -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770185/how-to-list-all-the-trips-discarding-one-airline . @Willem Van Onsem