# How to list all the trips discarding one airline

Tags: prolog

This is my flights data

```
#flight(city1, city2,airline,distance,time,price).
flight(dublin, london,ab,8000,4,1000).
flight(moscow,london,ab,9000,5,2000).
flight(dublin,moscow,bc,1000,6,3000).
flight(cork, moscow,ca,2000,7,4000).
flight(chicago, dublin,ab,6000,8,4500).
flight(berlin, moscow,bc,3000,9,4600).
flight(cork, newyork,ca,4000,10,4700).
flight(paris, hongkong,bc,11000,11,4890).

connected(X,Y,_,_,_,_) :- flight(X,Y,_,_,_,_) ; flight(Y,X,_,_,_,_).
```

I have to get all the trips between city1 and city2 discarding one airline

I have calculated the trip something like

```
trips(A,B,Path) :- 
      traverse(A,B,[A],Q),
      reverse(Q,Path).
 traverse(A,B,P,[B|P]) :-
         connected(A,B,_,_,_,_).
  traverse(A,B,Visited,Path) :-
         connected(A,C,_,_,_,_),
         C \== B,
         \+member(C,Visited),
         traverse(C,B,[C|Visited],Path).
```

This is the all_trip

```
Alltrip(C,L,T):-
      findall(Ci, trips(C,L,Ci), T).
```

I have to compute this

`Alltrip_noairline(X,Y,T,A):-` where X and Y are city ,T is the list of all trips and DISCARD all the trip containing a flight with airline A

I am  stuck here ,don't know how to start ,any help would be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: You need to add the list of the airlines in trips/3 (it will turn into trips/4?) then add \+member(A,Airlines) in findall next to trips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `connected/6` is in fact `flight/6`

You may add a Filter goal to your procedures:

```
trips(A,B,Filter, Path) :-
  traverse(A,B,Filter, [A],Q),
  reverse(Q,Path).

traverse(A,B, Filter, P,[B|P]) :-
  flight(A,B,Airline,_,_,_),
  call(Filter, Airline).
traverse(A,B, Filter, Visited,Path) :-
  flight(A,C,Airline,_,_,_),
  C \== B,
  call(Filter, Airline),
   \+ member(C,Visited),
  traverse(C,B, Filter, [C|Visited],Path).
```

Then in `alltrip/3` use a filter that accepts any airline:

```
alltrip(C,L,T):-
   findall(Ci, trips(C,L, any, Ci), T).

any(_).
```

and in `alltrip_noairline/4` one that forbids certain airline:

```
alltrip_noairline(C,L,T, A):-
   findall(Ci, trips(C,L, except(A), Ci), T).   

except(X, Y):- X\=Y.
```